# Haskell averageRate from list

Tags: haskell

Ive got this project to do Im kind of stuck. I know that is something not too complicated but I run out of ideas.

Well I defined those types:

```
-- Types
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Mark = Int
type Rating = (String, Int)

-- Define Film type here
type Film = (Title, Director, Year, [Rating])


-- Define database type here
type Database = [Film]


testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase =
  [("Casino Royale", "Martin Campbell", 2006, [("Garry",8),("Dave", 0)])
  ,("Blade Runner", "Ridley Scott", 1982, [("Amy",5),("Dave", 9]),
  ,("The Fly", "David Cronenberg", 1986, [("Fred",7),("Dave", 4)])
  ]
```

So now I have to display the average Rating, and after that I have to display the films which their average is equal or higher than 6.

Could you give me some hints / guidance please?  Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks for your replies, but because I already did half of the project, I think its to late to change the data types cause I have to reconsider everything.

I made a attempt but the display function it doesn't working, and I don't know why:

```
filmRating :: [Rating] -> Int
filmRating rating = div (sum [r | (_,r) <- rating]) (length rating)

averageFilm :: Film -> Int
averageFilm (t, d, y, r) = filmRating r


sixOrHigher :: Int -> Bool
sixOrHigher average
    | average <= 6 = True
    | otherwise = False


displayAverage :: Database -> String
displayAverage database = displayFilms (filter ((sixOrHigher (averageFilm)) database))
```

UPDATE2:

I found the solution after of hours of brain-killing and swearing at everything :)

Thanks again everyone!

Here it is:

```
averageFilm :: Film -> Int
averageFilm (t, d, y, r) = filmRating r

averageFilms :: Database -> [Int]
averageFilms database = map (averageFilm) database

sixOrHigher :: Int -> Bool
sixOrHigher average
            | average <= 6 = True
            | otherwise = False


checkAllIfHigher :: Film -> Bool 
checkAllIfHigher film = (sixOrHigher (averageFilm film))

displayAverage :: Database -> String
displayAverage database = displayFilmsAverage (filter (checkAllIfHigher) database)


displayFilmsAverage :: Database -> String
displayFilmsAverage database = concat(map (displayFilmAverage ) database)
```

Comment: first step: write a function `:: Film -> [Rating]` that gets all ratings of a film. From that, a function `:: [Rating] -> Double` that makes an average. Then you can look into the provided sort-by functions.

Comment: Have a look at the `map` function [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) and the `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a` and `length :: [a] -> Int` functions. Later you'll need the `filter` function [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) to select films. You can search for functions on [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/).

Comment: Your `Mark` type synonym isn't used anywhere - maybe you meant to use it when defining `Rate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: prefer data types to tuple+type synonym whenever possible.  Type synonyms are good if you want to give a different name to an existing type, but defining a custom data type also gives you type safety, so that you can not e.g. simply use *any* tuple instead of a *Rating*.

So your data types would become:

```
data Rating = Rating { ratingUsername :: String
                     , ratingStars :: Int 
                     }

data Film = Film { filmTitle :: String
                 , filmDirector :: String
                 , filmYear :: Int
                 , filmRatings :: [Rating]
                 }
```

and your testDatabase:

```
testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [ Film "Casino Royale" "Martin Campbell" 2006
                        [Rating "Garry" 8, Rating "Dave" 0]
               , Film "Blade Runner" "Ridley Scott" 1982
                        [Rating "Amy" 5, Rating "Dave" 9]
               , Film "The Fly" "David Cronenberg" 1986
                        [Rating "Fred" 7, Rating "Dave" 4]
               ]
```

Using our new datatypes, we can select only the ratings from a film via `filmRatings :: Film -> [Rating]`.

A good way to tackle this kind of problem is to first think of the needed type annotations and then go on implementing these with the help of [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle)

So to calculate the average ratings here are the steps you should try:

- define a function to calculate the average rating (you might want to look at e.g. `foldl` and friends)

  ```
  averageStars :: [Rating] -> Double
  ```
- to filter based on a property of the rating, you can then use filter with a appropiate predicate:

  ```
  filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
  ```

  where `(a -> Bool)` is in your case `Film -> Bool` so you would write a function

  ```
  goodFilm :: Film -> Bool
  ```

  and use your averageStars function defined before to compare if the rating is high enough.